# MapReduce - Anything else except word-counting?

Tags: multithreading, mapreduce

I have been looking at MapReduce and reading through various papers about it and applications of it, but, to me, it seems that MapReduce is only suitable for a very narrow class of scenarios that ultimately result in word-counting.

If you look at the [original paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) Google's employees provide "various" potential use cases, like "distributed grep", "distributed sort", "reverse web-link graph", "term-vector per host", etc.
But if you look closer, all those problems boil down to simply "counting words" - that is counting the number occurrences of something in a chunk of data, then aggregating/filtering  and sorting that list of occurrences.

There also are some cases where MapReduce has been used for genetic algorithms or relational databases, but they don't use the "vanilla" MapReduce published by Google. Instead they introduce further steps along the Map-Reduce chain, like Map-Reduce-Merge, etc.

Do you know of any other (documented?) scenarios where "vanilla" MapReduce has been used to perform more than mere word-counting? (Maybe for ray-tracing, video-transcoding, cryptography, etc. - in short anything "computation heavy" that is parallelizable)

Comment: I recall that the computational heavy-lifting behind [God's Number is 20](http://cube20.org/) was done by MapReduce, but I cannot find sources to cite at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapReduce is good for problems that can be considered to be embarrassingly parallel. There are a lot of problems that MapReduce is very bad at, such as those that require lots of all-to-all communication between nodes. E.g., fast Fourier transforms and signal correlation.

Comment: Consider Apache [Giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/) and [Hama](http://incubator.apache.org/hama/) when there is a lot of communication between nodes. Giraph is based on [Google Pregel](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/large-scale-graph-computing-at-google.html).Hama is based on [BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel). Note that both are in incubator status, but looking promising.

Comment: There is now an impressive collection of mapreduce algorithms for a large variety of problems (several references in the other answers). That someone can just disseminate FUD and have his answer marked as correct is what makes me less willing to engage in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Atbrox had been maintaining `mapreduce hadoop algorithms in academic papers`. Here is the [link](http://atbrox.com/2011/11/09/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-5th-update-%E2%80%93-nov-2011/). All of these could be applied for practical purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are projects using MapReduce for parallel computations in statistics. For instance, Revolutions Analytics has started a [RHadoop project](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/09/mapreduce-hadoop-r.html%20RHadoop) for use with R. Hadoop is also used in [computational biology](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19357099) and in other fields with large datasets that can be analyzed by many discrete jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of one of the packages in RHadoop and I wrote the several examples distributed with the source and used in the Tutorial, logistic regression, linear least squares, matrix multiplication etc. There is also a paper I would like to recommend http://www.mendeley.com/research/sorting-searching-simulation-mapreduce-framework/
that seems to strongly support the equivalence of mapreduce with classic parallel programming models such as PRAM and BSP. I often write mapreduce algorithms as ports from PRAM algorithms, see for instance blog.piccolboni.info/2011/04/map-reduce-algorithm-for-connected.html. So I think the scope of mapreduce is clearly more than "embarrassingly parallel" but not infinite. I have myself experienced some limitations for instance in speeding up some MCMC simulations. Of course it could have been me not using the right approach. My rule of thumb is the following: if the problem can be solved in parallel in O(log(N)) time on O(N) processors, then it is a good candidate for mapreduce, with O(log(N)) jobs and constant time spent in each job. Other people and the paper I mentioned seem to focus more on the O(1) jobs case. When you go beyond O(log(N)) time the case for MR seems to get a little weaker, but some limitations may be inherent in the current implementation (high job overhead) rather the fundamental. It's a pretty fascinating time to be working on charting the MR territory.